# Type mismatch: connectedcompany already defined with conflicting type Any (expected Node)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using Neo4j Community 3.4 with APOC 3.4.0.1 and running the following query:

```
MATCH (a:COMPANY)
WITH apoc.coll.randomItems(collect(a), count(a)/100) as companies
UNWIND companies as company
MATCH (b:COMPANY)
WITH collect(b) as companies, company
WITH company, apoc.coll.randomItem(companies) as connectedcompany
CREATE (connectedcompany)-[:IS_SHAREHOLDER_OF]->(company);
```

The query is meant to create select 1% of the companies in my database and link them randomly to another company by a IS_SHAREHOLDER_OF relationship.

The query results in the following message

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Type mismatch: connectedcompany
>   already defined with conflicting type Any (expected Node) (line 7,
>   column 9 (offset: 250)) "CREATE
>   (connectedcompany)-[:IS_SHAREHOLDER_OF]->(company);"

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide the full version of Neo4j you're using? We don't know the patch number of the version. Also, please provide the APOC version you're using. Lastly, can you explain verbally what this query is meant to do, so we can verify you're using an idea approach?

Comment: You still haven't provided the full version number, unless you mean 3.4.0. If you are on 3.4.0, you should immediately upgrade to the latest patch release, as initial .0 releases tend to be buggy, this one certainly included.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using 3.4.0 indeed. I will upgrade !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you can get off 3.4.0 and to the latest 3.4.x patch release you should be able to avoid that bug.

As for the query itself, you're doing an unnecessary match to (b:COMPANY). You previously matched to all companies, so you can reuse the list:

```
MATCH (a:COMPANY)
WITH collect(a) as allCompanies
WITH allCompanies, apoc.coll.randomItems(allCompanies, size(allCompanies)/100) as companies
UNWIND companies as company
WITH company, apoc.coll.randomItem(allCompanies) as connectedcompany
CREATE (connectedcompany)-[:IS_SHAREHOLDER_OF]->(company);
```

I threw in the shuffling of allCompanies as an alternate approach to consider, but your randomItems() approach will work just as well.